# Mix two tables SQL result

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio

In my SqlDataSource SQL command I want to output a mix of two tables.

I have a table **Matches** which contains *MatchDate*, *MatchTime*, *HomeTeamID* and *AwayTeamID*.

I have a second table **Teams** which contains *TeamID* and *TeamName*.

I want the result to display the columns *MatchDate*, *MatchTime*, *HomeTeamName* and *AwayTeamName*.
This is for an ASP.NET project in visual studios if that helps.

Thanks!!

Comment: SELECT TOP 5 [MatchDate], [MatchTime], [HomeTeamID], [AwayTeamID] FROM [Matches], [Teams] WHERE Matches.HomeTeamID = Teams.TeamID AND ([HomeTeamScore] IS NOT NULL)

Comment: Thats what i have after joining the two but i dont know how to change the HomeTeamID and AwayTeamID outputs to their respective team names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the query:

```
 select a.MatchDate, a.MatchTime, b.TeamName as HomeTeamName, c.TeamName as AwayTeamID from Matches a 
 inner join Teams b on a.HomeTeamID = b.TeamID 
 inner join Teams c on a.AwayTeamID = c.TeamID
```